# VBA Sub to Copy Formulas In Selection As Text

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste, excel-addins

I am a finance student with some basic programming knowledge (took Programming 2 at my uni which used C++ a few years ago) but no VBA experience. I want to develop a small custom excel add-in for a student organization which includes some subs that would save a lot of time when creating our Excel files, which get pretty large.

The first two of these subs are for this: I would like to be able to ***copy and paste the formulas from one cell range to another without changing the cell references*** in the formulas. To use the sub, one of our members would simply use an assigned hotkey. For example, the excel user could select a range of cells and hit (ctrl + alt + shift + c) to copy and (ctrl + alt + shift + v) to paste.

I attempted to create the copy sub but was unsuccessful, since I do not know how to properly use / iterate through Ranges, or even when to use Ranges vs multidimensional arrays. I also had trouble finding an answer to this specific use case online, so I would greatly appreciate anyone pointing me to further resources on the topic or any sample code, if possible.

For more color, please see the rough psuedocode and current progress on the sub below:

**Psuedocode - Copy Sub**

- *Comment - Copies formulas in Selection as text to clipboard*
- (1) Get user Selection's number of Rows and Columns *(I successfully did this)*
- (2) Create either a Range or Array with same dimensions as Selection
- (3) For each Cell in myRange / index in myArray, the value equals the formula for the corresponding cell in Selection, converted to text
- (3) Copy myRange / myArray to clipboard

**Psuedocode - Paste Sub**

- (1) Paste contents of clipboard (myRange / myArray) as text
- (2) If necessary, format these pasted contents as formulas

**Current progress - Copy Sub**

```
Sub CopyFormulasAsText()
    ' General documentation:
        ' This sub is intened to allow one to copy and paste formulas without changing the cell references
        ' In particular, this sub simply copies all formulas in the user selection as text
        ' with the same references embedded
        
    
    ' define variables
    Dim selctnRowCount As Integer
    Dim selctnColCount As Integer
    
    ' assign values to variables. These values are the number of rows and columns in the user selection
    selctnRowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
    selctnColCount = Selection.Columns.Count

    ' create an A x B size matrix, where A and B are the number of rows and columns in the user selection area, respectively
    ' this array will hold the formulas in each cell, which we will then copy to the clipboard as text
    
    Dim formulasArray(selctnRowCount, selctnColCount) As String
    
    ' I am unclear what next steps to take in this sub, or whether my my formulasArray should be a Range

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Mech, I have updated my post to include my current progress.

Comment: If you have `FORMULATEXT` function available to you then you can do this fairly straightforward way by referencing the cells without VBA e.g. `=FORMULATEXT(A1)` etc.

Comment: Thank you @shrivallabha.redij. I know how to use FORMULATEXT(), and I know other methods to workaround this problem in Excel, but they all take some short amount of time, which is the issue. That solution does not fix my use case. I would like to complete this macro because although it saves a small amount of time in one instance, it adds up significantly in the long run

Comment: So why do you want to copy the formulas as text and then back into formulas? Not 100% this is what you're looking for but you can just do `Range(ReceivingRange).Formula = Range(CopyingFormula).Formula`. This basically duplicates the formula in the new range. It also doesn't change the references as well. The advantage of doing it this way (if you can) instead of copying/pasting is it is much much faster.